# Change Dynamically Data Source's xml source on Dashcode

Tags: javascript, iphone, dashcode

Classic StackLayout-List(s) scenario. 
StackLayout have: *Home* - *Detail* - *Leaf*

On "Home" I have a Datasource like this:

```
<row><name>Element 1</name><resource>../Element1.xml</resource></row>
<row><name>Element 2</name><resource>../Element2.xml</resource></row>
```

This is binded to a list of name "*homeList*". onClick on "Element 1" i load Detail.

Detail have a list, let's call it "*detailList*", the problem is that i have to "bind" at runtime this list with resource element from previous selection.